# Isolate and use only one case from switch for using only one trackbar

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

I have code that receives data from the network and makes some trackbars move.

Each trackbar moves according to the corresponding channel.

For that to happen there is a "switch" statement:

```
private void OnChannelFade(object sender, OSCPacket packet)
    {   
       this.BeginInvoke(new ThreadSafeOSC(ThreadSafeOnChannelFade), packet.ToParams());            
    }

    private void ThreadSafeOnChannelFade(OSCPacket packet)
    {
         TrackBar trackBar = GetTrackBarFromChannel(Convert.ToInt32(packet.Nodes[2]));

           trackBar.Tag = packet;
          trackBar.Value = (int)(packet.Arguments[0].ToFloat() * 100);
    }

    private TrackBar GetTrackBarFromChannel(int channel)
    {
        pan2.Value = channel;
        switch (channel)
        {
            case 1:
            case 9:
            case 17:
            case 25:

                return fader1;
```

How do I isolate one case, in other words how do I link one trackbar to get data from only one channel?

Comment: I have a really hard time understanding what you are trying to ask here... `isolate one case` what do you mean when talking about "isolating"? `only 1 trackbar to get data from only 1 channel` What do you mean with this? Isn't getting the  trackbar associated with a particular channel also a part of what _ThreadSafeOnChannelFade_ does; so why would you ask about something your own code above already demonstrates? Do i misunderstand you?

Comment: This is hard to explain, this code is controlling 8 trackbars using 32 channels. each trackbar is routed to a few channels using th "switch" statement when case(channel) 1 is returning to trackbar 1 and cases 9,17,25.... is returning to trackbar 2 etc... what i want is to refer only one channel to one trackbar without using the switch command on i dont kno the syntax. something like "trackbar1.value - channel (1);" this is wrong ofcourse

Comment: where the hell fader1 comes from?

Comment: fader1 is a trackbar